# How can a Pakistani visit Israel (particularly one who is a Christian)?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, israel, religion

With a Pakistani passport, a person can travel to any country in the world without any problem, except for Israel. When it comes to travel to Israel, one can only think about it, as there are no diplomatic relations between Pakistan and Israel.

A Muslim Pakistani does not mind but, when it comes to Christian minorities, it becomes more relevant and important as they want to visit the religious holy places. Yet, they are treated as any other citizen of Pakistan.

Is there any legal way for them to visit Israel without any long and difficult procedures?

Comment: It is certainly not limited to Christians! Even Muslims may wish to visit Al-Aqsa mosque.

Comment: I know a few Pakistanis that did travel to Israel. But that was almost 20 years ago. They were issued a paper visa; the Pakistani passport was not used. I don't know how it would work now--provided you are able to acquire a visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton absolutely right sir but my question is Muslims in Pakistan are in majority so they are to follow their country law as it is but for minorities e.g Christians there are no such exceptions that allow them to visit Israel.

Comment: _"A Muslim Pakistani does not mind but, when it comes to Christian minorities, it becomes more relevant and important as they want to visit the religious holy places."_ I'd say that this statement is too general. As far as I know, there are places in Israel that are sacred to muslims too (however probably not as many). On the other hand, I am christian and I have no desire what so ever to visit Israel at all.

Comment: See similar questions: [about Malaysia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22179/is-it-possible-to-travel-to-israel-if-its-not-recognised-by-your-passports-cou), [about Lebanon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122041/can-one-visit-israel-with-a-lebanese-passport-only)

Comment: I would recommend Pakistani citizens to ask questions about travelling to Israel from a fake profile and not one that has their name, picture and place of residence.

Comment: When I visited Israel some years ago, the ban even extended to UK citizens who had a stamp in the passport from certain nations, such as Jordan where I arrived from. I obtained a temporary permit to enter Israel but had to leave my passport in Jordan.

Comment: ... so the policy had nothing to do with my own religion or ethnicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Israel does not have an embassy or consulate in Pakistan (nor do they in many other countries). To apply for a visa, you will need to make your application through an [Israeli embassy or consulate in a different country](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/ConsularServices.aspx). The linked MFA web site has a list of all the consulates worldwide.

[The visa application process](http://mfa.gov.il/MFA/ConsularServices/Pages/Visas.aspx) is mostly the same as for people of any other nationality, but all applications from Pakistani nationals must also be approved by the Israel Ministry of Foreign Affairs, which will add a significant delay to the process, (one embassy web site states it could [add 30 days or more](http://embassies.gov.il/hague-en/ConsularServices/Pages/local-visa-information.aspx)) and if you are refused, you might not be told the reason for refusal.

Pakistani passport holders who are approved for a visa will receive the visa on a separate sheet of paper, not in the passport. The visa and any entrance/exit stamps will be placed on that paper, not in your passport (though Israel has mostly stopped entry/exit stamping entirely by now). You will need to take both your passport and the paper with the visa when you travel to Israel.

Keep in mind that it is Pakistan that does not want you traveling to Israel. Israel makes its own decisions in regard to who can visit, and does not care that your passport says it is not valid for travel to Israel. This is one reason why they place the visa on a separate paper. Along the same lines, you should be careful when booking flights. If you book a single ticket from Pakistan to Israel, then the government will know that you intend to travel there.

Note that even with a visa, Pakistanis report that they typically spend several hours passing through the Israeli border and answering a large number of questions. You should be mentally prepared for this experience.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great information.As you mentioned very clearly that Israel does not have an embassy or consulate in Pakistan therefore it becomes mandatory for them to go to any country having israel consulate first and then they can travel to Israel

Comment: A Pakistani passport specifically excludes Israel from its validity. Pakistani travellers can expect no help from their government if they encounter difficulties; travel insurance bought in Pakistan may not be valid in Israel; Timatic suggests that a valid passport is required to enter Israel, but the Pakistani passport is explicitly invalid so airlines might refuse to board Pakistani passengers bound for Israel.