# Why can we go to every country by using Pakistani passport, but not Israel?

Tags: passports, pakistani-citizens, israel

Through a Pakistani passport we can go to every country but we cannot go to Israel. What is reason behind this issue?

Comment: Pakistan does not [recognize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_recognition) Israel.  The reasons for *that* are outside the scope of this site, but could be asked on [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The *reason* behind this could (and does) fill many books. I'm voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Politics.SE

Comment: You can go to Israel with a Pakistani passport if you obtain a visa.

Comment: Very closely related to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125185/how-can-a-pakistani-visit-israel-particularly-one-who-is-a-christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason because Pakistan does not recognize Israel as nation this is an issue related to politics because I think Israel also not recognizes Pakistan although it is clearly written on Pakistan's passport that it is not valid for Israel but Pakistanis can visit Israel. Though Pakistani Passport is not valid for Israel but Israel Government has directed the Borders Control that Pakistanis should not be denied to visit Israel, therefore, whenever any Pakistani arrives at Israeli border, they issue a paper visa and put all the entry-exit stamps on that visa as Pakistani passport is not valid for travel to Israel. Pakistanis don’t need passport of any other country to enter Israel because they can get paper visa on Israeli borders.
 Just Google. [Many Pakistanis have mentioned about their visit to Israel](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-Pakistani-citizen-visit-Israel).

Diplomatic ties have not been established between Pakistan & Israel and as a Muslim-majority country, Pakistan has refused to recognize Israel. Nevertheless, Pakistan and Israel use their Embassies at Istanbul to mediate or exchange information with each other.

Comment: Pakistan doesn't recognise Israel but the Pakistani passport says its not valid in Israel? Thats weird. Sounds like recognition

Comment: @theotherone It doesn't recognise Israel as a valid state; it doesn't pretend that nobody's heard of a place called Israel that _others_ consider to be a valid state